# Importhtml rename header name Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("url1","table",2),"select Col1, Col5,' '
 where Col1 is not null
label ' ''Hour 2'",1), {"",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("url2","table",2),"select Col1, ' ',Col5
 where Col1 is not null offset 1",1), {"",""}) })
```

The auto generated first two column headers should be labeled 'Company', 'Hour 1'
I tried label Col1 'Company' or label A 'Company' but neither worked.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, you are joining 2 queries of `IMPORTHTML` another query.
However, in the first column, you are selecting 2 columns and in the second one, you are fetching other 2 columns.

If you want to label any column, you can address that by doing the following in the query section inside query:

```
select Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null label Col1 'Company', Col5 'Hour 1'
       ^^^^  ****                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  *************
```

You query can become the following:

```
{
IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("url1","table",2),"select Col1, Col5,' '
 where Col1 is not null
label Col1 'Company', Col5 'Hour1', ' ' 'Hour 2'",1), {"",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)","table",4),"select Col1, ' ',Col5
 where Col1 is not null offset 1",1), {"",""})
}
```

Note: I removed the `query({something; something})` as it has the same result as just `{something; something}`